# How do SciKit-Learn Pipelines pass Data between Steps?

Tags: scikit-learn, pipelines, transformation

I would like to create some Custom Transformers and incorporate them in a SciKit-Learn `Pipeline`.

I'd like to pass more than just a Dataframe between the transformer steps in the pipeline. For example, I'd like to create a Custom Transformer that uses pandas's `get_dummies()` function to encode categorical variables, then I would like to pass the columns that it considered categorical to a [`ColumnTransformer`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer.html) object, so that the pipeline automatically treatments them differently.

I can't see an easy way to do this, so I realise this may take some effort. How does SciKit-Learn pass Data between steps in its pipeline?